# Python fit with normalized parameters

Tags: python-2.7, scipy, lmfit

If I define fitting function as:

```
def func(a1,a2,a3,a4):
    return a1*y1+a2*y2+a3*y3+a4*y4
```

and when i fit I want to tie my parameters:

```
a1**2+a2**2+a3**2+a4**2=1
```

I cannot find the way to do that with scipy.optimize or lmfit module.

Do you have any suggestion?

Thanks!

Comment: What are `y1`, `y2`, `y3` and `y4` in `func()`?  Constants?

Comment: they are just some arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Just to be clear, your `func()` is not actually how you write a fitting function for scipy optimize or lmfit.  You have given very little context for your problem, which limits how much help can be given.

But, for constraining parameter values, the key is to recognize that there are actually three variable parameters and one parameter whose value is derived from the others, say `a1`, `a2`, and `a3` vary and `a4` is defined as

```
a4 = sqrt(1 - a1**2 - a2**2 - a3**2)
```

This can be done easily with lmfit (see docs and examples for more details):

```
from lmfit import Model, Parameters

def func(y1, y2, y3, y4, a1, a2, a3, a4):
    return  y1*a1**2 + y2*a2**2 + y3*a3**2 + y4*a4**2 

model = Model(func, independent_vars=['y1', 'y2', 'y3', 'y4'])

params = Parameters()
params.add('a1', value=0.5, vary=True)
params.add('a2', value=0.5, vary=True)
params.add('a3', value=0.5, vary=True)
params.add('a4', expr='sqrt(1 - (a1**2 + a2**2 + a3**2))')

result = model.fit(params, ydata, y1=y1, y2=y2, y3=y3, y4=y4)
```

Of course, you may have to look out for `(a1**2 + a2**2 + a3**2)` exceeding 1.0.   You could, for example, place bounds on the values for parameters `a1`, etc.